# How to number JSF error messages and attach number to invalid component

Tags: jsf, error-handling

I want to number any JSF error messages (e.g. validation, conversion messages) that appears if a user enters invalid input in a couple of input fields. For example like this when the user sends the form:

---

1. Name cannot contain numbers
2. E-mail is incorrect

----- Form ------

(1) Name: John 13 Doe

Age: 30

(2) E-mail: myemail@domain

---

How can I do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the messages part, just display them all using `<h:messages/>` the usual way which you style as `list-style-type: decimal;`. That would display the numbers instead of bullets.

Next step would be numbering the labels. This requires a bit more work as JSF doesn't provide any builtin facility to figure that. Basically you'll need to determine whether the label in question has a message associated or not and in which order the message has been enqueued. You could collect this information into a `Map<String, String>` as follows:

```
private Map<String, String> messageIndexes;

public Map<String, String> getMessageIndexes() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (messageIndexes == null && context.getRenderResponse()) {
         messageIndexes = new HashMap<String, String>();
         Iterator<String> clientIds = context.getClientIdsWithMessages();
         for (int i = 1; clientIds.hasNext(); i++) {
             messageIndexes.put(clientIds.next(), String.format("(%d)", i));
         }
    }
    return messageIndexes;
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.messageIndexes['form:input1']}" />
    <h:outputLabel for="input1">Label 1</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}" required="true" />
    <br />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.messageIndexes['form:input2']}" />
    <h:outputLabel for="input2">Label 2</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}" required="true" />
    <br />
    ...
</h:form>
```

If the client ID is not present in the map, then simply nothing will be rendered.

To move all the job out of the bean, you may consider either a `PhaseListener` (do it in the `beforePhase()` of the `RENDER_RESPONSE`), or a custom label component.

Comment: @BalusC The BalusC resource about Java Server Faces book. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I used your solution and did some minor changes. I solved it by using a PhaseListener for RENDER_RESPONSE phase. However, I did have to call method below from beforePhase() instead of afterPhase(). Otherwise my changes had no effect.

```
public void addMessageIdentifier() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getRenderResponse()) {

        // Iterate over faces messages and add counter
        Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = context.getMessages();
        if (messages != null && messages.hasNext()) {
            int counter = 1;
            while (messages.hasNext()) {
                FacesMessage message = messages.next();
                if (message.getSeverity().equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR)) {
                    String indicator = "(" + new Integer(counter).toString() + ") ";
                    message.setDetail(indicator);
                    message.setSummary(indicator + message.getSummary());
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the you need `beforePhase()`, I don't know why I said `afterPhase()`, sorry about that. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted, else the question will remain unanswered.