# Display JSF element only if specific h:message is being displayed

Tags: jsf-2

I have a `h:form` with several inputs and each of them got its own `h:message` and I'm looking for a way to show (using `render` or assigning some `styleClass`) some other element only when specific `h:message` is being shown (and hide when that `h:message` is not being displayed).

Here a code snippet

```
<li>
    <h:panelGroup id="current_password_wrapper">
        <p:password value="#{myBean.myCurrPass}" id="current_password" required="true"
            styleClass="required_field" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:message for="current_password"/>
</li>
<li>
    <h:panelGroup id="new_password_wrapper">
        <p:password value="#{myBean.myNewPass}" id="new_password" required="true"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:message for="new_password"/>
    <h:commandLink value="my value"/>
</li>
```

I want to make the `h:commandLink` visible only when the `<h:message for="new_password"/>` is being displayed

So far I couldn't find anything...

Comment: Do you want to create some kind of validation for input elements?

Comment: Is the message being shown on a validation error of a certain component? If so, which one?

Comment: @BalusC , I populating `<h:message for="new_password"/>` with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage` from my bean for *new_password* id when the value in `myNewPass` is invalid (I also use that h:message for `required="true"` but it won't be a problem to add another h:message just for myNewPass validation error that is being checked in the bean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your environment supports EL 2.2, then you could check if [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28java.lang.String%29) isn't `empty` for the particular client ID.

```
<p:password binding="#{new_password}" ... />
<h:commandLink ... rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(new_password.clientId)}" />
```

If the message is being shown as result of a validation error, then you could also just check the [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) state of the component associated with the message.

```
<p:password binding="#{new_password}" ... />
<h:commandLink ... rendered="#{not new_password.valid}" />
```

Note that manually adding a faces message to the context won't mark the input component invalid. Therefor either a true `Validator` should be used which throws a `ValidatorException`, or an explicit `input.setValid(false)` call has to be done programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, used `input.setValid(false)` and `rendered="#{not new_password.valid}"`. But is there any way to display a certain element based on if some h:message is being visible or not ? I mean to use `binding` on `<h:message` itself...

Comment: @BalusC Sounds like a good idea for omnifaces! `<inputText styleClassOnError="" />`

Comment: @Ben: `<o:highlight>` already does that: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight

Answer (score 2):

I think with the answer to this question you requirement can be archived:

[How to number JSF error messages and attach number to invalid component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503921/how-to-number-jsf-error-messages-and-attach-number-to-invalid-component)

I think you can do something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="output text" rendered="#{bean.messageIndexes['form:input1'] > 0}" />
```

Comment: With a custom Validator you could also archive the goal.